# Unit Testing failing with NullPoiterException

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, nullpointerexception, jetbrains-ide

Hi i'm new to programming and i started doing unit testing.I have problem with NullPointerException.
I think something is broken in my InteliJ when i update it.My teachers type same code but their tests are passing.Here is what i should Test:

```
 @Before
public void SetUp() {
   this.motorcycle= new UnitMotorcycle("Nissan", 70, 120);
}

@Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
public void testShouldThrowNullException() {
    UnitRider unitRider = new UnitRider(null, motorcycle);
}
@Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
public void testNameShouldBeNull() {
    UnitRider unitRider = new UnitRider(null, motorcycle);
    assertNull(unitRider.getName());
}
@Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
public void testNameAndMotorShouldBeNull() {
    UnitRider unitRider = new UnitRider("", null);
    assertEquals("",unitRider.getName());
}
```

Here is the method i am testing:

```
 public String addRider(UnitRider rider) {
    if (rider == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException(RIDER_INVALID);
    }
```

And my testing is failing and give me NullPointerException is expected.
Like i did what my teacher.And I think it was from update and i preinstall with diffrent versions of inteliJ but still dont't working.I'm using Java 11, Junit 4.12 and Maven 11

Comment: I don't see a test that calls `addRider`.

Comment: Please read: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) --- I highly doubt that IntelliJj is the root cause. IntelliJ ist just an IDE. One could do everything without an IDE.

Comment: @Turing85 and Ted Hopp thank you so much!!!! After debugging 3 hours and with your help i figured out the problem. NullPointerException don't works with newly created object so i should modify it with method to be null.Sorry for don't know how to up your comments :( and again thank you very much.

Comment: @TedHopp //////////////